# how to traverse a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I've three boxes ,each one fades in, shakes then fades out.
The ID of each one reserved in an array and a loop traverses them,the loop works correctly but  just shows the first item!.

I've checked the javascript with different ways using for loop,delay instead of setTimeout
.I've also tried to add the boxes in html not in js file
(if it casued any problems!!!!!!!!)

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=QLRAbwHOR7

could any one help me please???!!

```
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
            var imgID= ['red','green','blue'];
            $.each(imgID, function(i) {

                $(".image").append('<div class="box"fid="'+i+'">'+imgID[i]+'</div>');
                $('#'+i).fadeIn(500);
                setTimeout(function(){
                $('#'+i).effect( "shake",{times:5}, 1000 ).fadeOut(500);
                }, 1000);
                alert("ID: "+i);
            }); 
      });
```

Comment: That's not a valid JSFiddle link.

Comment: @ahren - the jsFiddle link worked for me (perhaps you have to be logged into jsFiddle).  It prompted me for collaboration.

Comment: Just an advice for the future: don't give jsfiddle link to the code you have problem with - currently at least 8 people work on the very same code so I bet it's not the version you had problem with...

Comment: To the original poster.  I pasted into your question the code I saw from your jsFiddle link.  Is that the code you're asking about?

Comment: @jfriend00 - ah, must be. Thanks for posting the code.

Comment: try this link:http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=mLIF3NJgOn

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in the question (not the jsfiddle link) I think the problem is on this line

```
$(".image").append('<div class="box"fid="'+i+'">'+imgID[i]+'</div>');
                                    ^
```

should be

```
$(".image").append('<div class="box" id="'+i+'">'+imgID[i]+'</div>');
                                    ^ remove the 'f'
```

here is my fiddle results
http://jsfiddle.net/jasrus/ZqayT/

**Update** Also make sure that you include jQueryUI because `effect` is not part of the jquery library

Comment: It works but this isn't what i want,based on your code see my change in the link:http://jsfiddle.net/jasrus/ZqayT/#run&togetherjs=9412G2o60T

Comment: I think the problem is the CSS not the code. The loop is defintely going through each imgID, but the overflow is set to hidden which means you can't see the additional items

The height of the image div is 200px and each box is also 200px

Comment: So you want to show imgID['red'], shake it, remove it, then show imgID['green'] and shake it, then remove it, then show imgID['blue'] and shake it?

Comment: Thnx a lot  @jasonscript, but I wonder from the flow of execution!!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: is it right that : the time between execution for each color in the array takes  milliseconds, so all boxes appear at same time with same delay and because of overflow:hidden just the red one will appear